# ES Analyzer which tokens the numbers, digits as well

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, analyzer, elasticsearch-analyzers

I am using Elasticsearch in-built Simple analyzer https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.7/analysis-simple-analyzer.html, which uses Lower Case Tokenizer. and text **apple 8 IS Awesome** is tokenized in the below format.

```
 "apple",
 "is",
 "awesome"
```

You can clearly see, that it misses tokenizing the number `8`, hence now if I just search with `8`, my message will not appear in search.

I went through all the available analyzer available with ES but couldn't find any suitable analyzer which matches my requirement.

How can I tokenize all the words with a number using a custom or in-built analyzer of ES ?

Comment: You haven't tried the `standard` analyzer then ;-)

Comment: The standard analyzer works for me and properly tokenizes 8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about the simple analyzer, but you mention a very old link to documentation. Try
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-simple-analyzer.html

Like Val told you, you probably looking for the [standard analyser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-standard-analyzer.html).
If you want to see the difference try the [analysis api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-analyze.html):

- http://localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=simple&text=apple%208%20IS%20Awesome
- http://localhost:9200/_analyze?analyzer=standard&text=apple%208%20IS%20Awesome