# Search for both numbers and text using a in-built or custom analyzer in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, tokenize, elasticsearch-analyzers

This question is in continuation of my previous [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46802733/in-built-elastic-search-analyzer-which-does-work-of-simple-analyzer-as-well-toke) SO question. I've some text, on which I want to perform search both on numbers and text.

My Text:-

> 8080.foobar.getFooLabelFrombar(test.java:91)

And I want to search on `getFooLabelFrombar`, `fooBar`, `8080` and `91`.

Earlier I was using the `simple` analyzer, which was tokenizing the above text into below tokens.

```
 "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "foobar",
      "start_offset": 10,
      "end_offset": 16,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "getfoolabelfrombar",
      "start_offset": 17,
      "end_offset": 35,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "test",
      "start_offset": 36,
      "end_offset": 40,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 4
    },
    {
      "token": "java",
      "start_offset": 41,
      "end_offset": 45,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 5
    }
  ]
}
```

Beaucase of which, search on `foobar` and `getFooLabelFrombar` was giving the search result but not `8080` and `91`, as **simple analyzer doesn't tokenize the numbers**.

Then as suggested in prev. SO post,  I changed the analyzer to `Standard`, because of which numbers are searchable but not other 2 word search strings. As Standard analyzer would create below tokens :-

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "8080",
      "start_offset": 0,
      "end_offset": 4,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "foobar.getfoolabelfrombar",
      "start_offset": 5,
      "end_offset": 35,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 2
    },
    {
      "token": "test.java",
      "start_offset": 36,
      "end_offset": 45,
      "type": "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position": 3
    },
    {
      "token": "91",
      "start_offset": 46,
      "end_offset": 48,
      "type": "<NUM>",
      "position": 4
    }
  ]
}
```

I went to all the existing analyzers in ES, but nothing seems to fulfil my requirement. I tried creating my below custom analyzer but it doesn't work as well.

```
{
    "analysis" : {
            "analyzer" : {
                "my_analyzer" : {
                    "tokenizer" : "letter"
                    "filter" : ["lowercase", "extract_numbers"]
                }
            },
            "filter" : {
                "extract_numbers" : {
                    "type" : "keep_types",
                    "types" : [ "<NUM>","<ALPHANUM>","word"]
                }
            }
        }
}
```

Please suggest, How can I build my custom analyzer to suit my requirements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a character filter to replace dots with spaces?

```
PUT /my_index
{                                                                                     
  "settings": {                                                                                                                                    
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {                                                                                                                                
        "my_analyzer": {                                                                                                                           
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": ["replace_dots"]
        }
      },
      "char_filter": {
        "replace_dots": {
          "type": "mapping",
          "mappings": [
            ". => \\u0020"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

POST /my_index/_analyze
{                                                                           
  "analyzer": "my_analyzer",                                            
  "text": "8080.foobar.getFooLabelFrombar(test.java:91)"
}
```

Which outputs what you want:

```
{                                                                               
  "tokens" : [
    {
      "token" : "8080",
      "start_offset" : 0,
      "end_offset" : 4,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 0
    },
    {
      "token" : "foobar",
      "start_offset" : 10,
      "end_offset" : 16,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 2
    },
    {
      "token" : "getFooLabelFrombar",
      "start_offset" : 17,
      "end_offset" : 35,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 3
    },
    {
      "token" : "test",
      "start_offset" : 36,
      "end_offset" : 40,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 4
    },
    {
      "token" : "java",
      "start_offset" : 41,
      "end_offset" : 45,
      "type" : "<ALPHANUM>",
      "position" : 5
    },
    {
      "token" : "91",
      "start_offset" : 46,
      "end_offset" : 48,
      "type" : "<NUM>",
      "position" : 6
    }
  ]
}
```